# How to get effective permission of a NTFS file using command line?

Tags: command-line, vbscript, file-permissions, ntfs, cacls

As per subject, is there a command or may be even a sample VBScript that I can use to calculate/read effective permission of a file in Windows XP and Windows Server 2003 OS? All I want is to be able to get same information as I see in "effective permission" tab of Security->Advanced option of a NTFS file.

Commands like calcs, icacls etc don't provide effective permission- they can list inherited permission but they don't *calculate* effective permission.

EDIT- Based upon below answer, it isn't really possible by means of using VB Script. I'll write a piece of code and then call it from VBScript

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sysinternals' [AccessChk](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb664922) should do the trick.

There is no built-in tool for this task. And I seriously doubt that calculating the effective permissions from VBScript is possible.

Programmatically the effective permissions can be determined by calling the API function [GetEffectiveRightsFromAcl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa446637%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) or using the more modern Authz API ([example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa446637%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), scroll down a little).

Comment: I'm looking for something native to OS - no third party tools. Thanks for suggestion though

Comment: Is it possible using any Windows API calls?

Comment: @HelgeKlein Your links to GetEffectiveRightsFromAcl and your Authz API example are links to the same page.  I think that's a typo.

Comment: @Jared: It certainly looks like a typo, but the example for Authz is on the page where GetEffectiveRightsFromAcl is described ("The following example shows using Authz API to get effective access rights from an ACL.").